# $X$ metric space, $A$ a subset, distance from $x$ to $A$ function $d(x,A) = \inf\{d(x,a) : a \in A\}$ continuous

Tags: general-topology, functions, metric-spaces, continuity

On page 175 of Munkres Topology he says $d(x,A)-d(y,A) \leq d(x,y)$ and the same inequality holds with $x$ and $y$ interchanged and that the continuity follows from this. How exactly does the continuity follow?

Comment: If $d(x,y) <\delta$, select $\epsilon = \delta$

Comment: I see, that's what I was looking at just now. Thanks